# cmake не обнаруживает ant

Tags: opencv, cmake, ant

Пытаюсь собрать opencv для java. Cmake ни в какую не видит ant. Вот его вывод при конфигурации:

```
Detected processor: x86_64
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.7")
Looking for ccache - not found
Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: JPEG_LIBRARY
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR
Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.0.6, BUILD = opencv-4.5.1-libjpeg-turbo
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: TIFF_LIBRARY
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR
Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: WEBP_LIBRARY
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: WEBP_INCLUDE_DIR
Could NOT find OpenJPEG (minimal suitable version: 2.0, recommended version >= 2.3.1). OpenJPEG will be built from sources
OpenJPEG: VERSION = 2.3.1, BUILD = opencv-4.5.1-openjp2-2.3.1
OpenJPEG libraries will be built from sources: libopenjp2 (version "2.3.1")
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: PNG_LIBRARY
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: PNG_INCLUDE_DIR
Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
  No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
Checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
  No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
Checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
  No package 'gthread-2.0' found
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2020.0.0 [2020.0.0 Gold]
at: /home/dym/IdeaProjects/opencv-4.5.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2020.0.0
at: /home/dym/IdeaProjects/opencv-4.5.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find Atlas (missing: Atlas_CBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR Atlas_CBLAS_LIBRARY Atlas_BLAS_LIBRARY Atlas_LAPACK_LIBRARY) 
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
/bin/ant: 1: cd: can't cd to /bin/../share/ant/bin/..

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher


VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/dym/IdeaProjects/opencv-4.5.1/build/python_loader
Checking for modules 'libavcodec;libavformat;libavutil;libswscale'
  No package 'libavcodec' found
  No package 'libavformat' found
  No package 'libavutil' found
  No package 'libswscale' found
FFMPEG is disabled. Required libraries: libavcodec;libavformat;libavutil;libswscale. Missing libraries: libavcodec;libavformat;libavutil;libswscale
Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
  No package 'libdc1394-2' found
Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /home/dym/IdeaProjects/opencv-4.5.1/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code

General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.1 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2021-02-03T16:24:23Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.4.0-65-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       3.16.3
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (17 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (7 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 10.2.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo stitching ts video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 python3
    Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.6-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.3.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      NO
      avcodec:                   NO
      avformat:                  NO
      avutil:                    NO
      swscale:                   NO
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /home/dym/IdeaProjects/opencv-4.5.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /home/dym/IdeaProjects/opencv-4.5.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/dym/IdeaProjects/opencv-4.5.1/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /home/dym/IdeaProjects/opencvJava
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

Следовал гайду [тык](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html). ant установлен с помощью apt. в .bashrc прописал
`export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant`
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
`export ANT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/share/ant/bin`
Ничего не помогает.

Comment: а то, что у вас еще куча либ не найдена вас не смущает? Пути то верно указали?

Comment: а вообще почему вы собираете opencv4 по инструкции к opencv3?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch доустановил FFMPEG. Пути проверил - всё так. Странно то, что ant даже не пытается искать.